Why can't Number.isInteger narrow type to number only?
Number.isInteger() doesn't narrow the type:
function checkNum(num: number | undefined ) {
    if (Number.isInteger(num)){
        console.log(typeof num)
                        //^? number | undefined
    } else {
        console.log(typeof num)
                        //^? number | undefined
    }
}

Playground
Besides having to assert it manually, is there other way to narrow it to number only? I want to use it with Math.floor().

Because ms/TS#58916. If Number.isInteger(num) narrowed to number in the true branch, it would narrow to undefined in the false branch, which we don't want. You could simulate one-sided type guards with branding as shown in this playground link, but it's not something TS is going to do automatically. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

Yes, it answers the question. Why does the brand/the intersection type not affect the number type? Does the number have to be converted to an object in order to do that?

See the linked q/a above for information. But I don't understand your followup question. What do you mean by "not affect"? How or why would the number be "converted" to an object? Could you rephrase?

I've elaborated it here
